# Export the Web Analytics in SharePoint 2010 using Powershel

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Is there any way to export the Web Analytics in SharePoint 2010 using Powershell?

The following link shows an example of the data I would like to retrieve, both on (Web collection and site collection) level.

[http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349%2D3bb6%2D4087%2D94f4%2D7f95ff4ca81f&ID=250&Web=48e6fdd1%2D17db%2D4543%2Db2f9%2D6fc7185484fc](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349-3bb6-4087-94f4-7f95ff4ca81f&ID=250&Web=48e6fdd1-17db-4543-b2f9-6fc7185484fc)

If there is another way to extract the data (i.e reporting services) that would be okay. E